# Get serial number of devices on ttyUSB0(Ubuntu)

Tags: linux

I have a 1 x USB to 8 x serial ports hub. I have connected 8 devices to the hub (ttyUSB0...7). I need a way to identify which device is at each ttyUSBx port.
I have tried the following command:

udevadm info -a -n /dev/ttyUSB1 | grep '{serial}' | head -n1

and looked at the log in:
/var/log/messages

as advised here:
http://hintshop.ludvig.co.nz/show/persistent-names-usb-serial-devices/

But what I get is the serial number and VendorID:ProductID of the USBtoSerial hub for all the ttyUSBx ports.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Use as this>>

```
sudo lshw |grep serial
```

You can find all details about device by type only sudo lshw

Comment: that's not really an answer... your command gives something like: `serial: xxxx\nserial:yyyyy\n`... without any information about what device is that... and `sudo lshw |grep USB` finds no matches, so the device is not there, or it's not described with it's `tty` end-point (as OP asked).